# XML-RPC call is munging special characters

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, xml-rpc, invision-power-board

For reasons beyond my control, I'm having to utilize an XML-RPC interface. My client is Ruby, the server is PHP. My problem is that any "special" characters in the message get altered along the way.

For example, here's a call I might make in Ruby:

```
server   = XMLRPC::Client.new2('http://mysite.com/path/to/server/')
response = server.call('postTopic', {
  :topic_title  => "Tsígö"
})
```

Note the two special characters in the `:topic_title` param.

When it reaches the server, this is what that log shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>postTopic</methodName>
   <params>
      <param>
         <value>
            <struct>
               <member>
                  <name>topic_title</name>
                  <value>
                     <string>TsÃ­gÃ¶</string>
                  </value>
               </member>
            </struct>
         </value>
      </param>
   </params>
</methodCall>
```

Comment: "TsÃ­gÃ¶" is "Tsígö" interpreted as an ISO-8859-1 (AKA Latin-1) encoded string. So, is the server actually UTF-8 aware or is it blindly treating everything as Latin-1 despite the specified encoding?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. Is that something that would be controlled by PHP itself or just the software managing the XMLRPC server? For what it's worth, the server is part of [IP.Board](http://www.invisionpower.com/products/board/).

Comment: I fixed it, I think. mu, since your comment put me on the right track, please feel free to add your comment as an answer and I'll upvote + accept.

Comment: Could be either one but anything that handles XML should be able to handle UTF-8; I'm no PHP guy so "I don't know" is the best answer I can offer. Check your out-bound HTTP headers to see if the charset is properly specified on your side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"TsÃ gÃ¶" is "Tsígö" interpreted as an ISO-8859-1 (AKA Latin-1) encoded string. So, is the server actually UTF-8 aware or is it blindly treating everything as Latin-1 despite the specified encoding?

Answer (score 2):

I believe I figured out the problem, thanks to mu's comment on my original post.

IP.Board's XMLRPC server was receiving the UTF-8 data correctly, but it wasn't *displaying* it correctly on the front end. The problem lied with a IP.Board configuration setting, "Character Encoding" in "Server Environment" that, for some reason, was set to ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. Changing the value to UTF-8 fixed the display issue.